# Problem with weight conversion program

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class WeightConverter
{
    private double numOfLbs2Conv, numOfKilos2Conv, converted2Pounds, converted2Kilograms;
    private final double WEIGHT_CONVERSION_FACTOR = 2.20462262;
    private int desiredDecimalPlaces;
    private boolean toKilos, toPounds;

    public void readPoundsAndConvert()
    {
       toKilos = true;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of pounds to convert to " 
            + "kilograms: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        numOfLbs2Conv = keyboard.nextDouble();
        converted2Pounds = numOfLbs2Conv / WEIGHT_CONVERSION_FACTOR;
    }


    public void readKilogramsAndConvert()
    {   
        toPounds = true;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of kilograms to convert to " 
            + "pounds: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        numOfKilos2Conv = keyboard.nextDouble();
        converted2Kilograms = numOfKilos2Conv * WEIGHT_CONVERSION_FACTOR;
    }


    public void displayBothValues()
    {
        System.out.print("How many places after the decimal would you like? ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        desiredDecimalPlaces = keyboard.nextInt();

        String decimalCounter = "0.";
        for (int i = 0; i < desiredDecimalPlaces; i++)
        {
          decimalCounter = decimalCounter + "0";
        }

        DecimalFormat decimalsConverted = new DecimalFormat(decimalCounter);              


        if (toKilos)
        {

          System.out.println("The number of kilograms in " 
            + decimalsConverted.format(numOfLbs2Conv) + " pounds is " 
            + decimalsConverted.format(converted2Kilograms) + ".");
        System.out.print("Press Enter to continue ... ");
        System.out.println("");
        keyboard.nextLine();
        }


        if (toPounds) 
        {

        System.out.println("The number of pounds in "
            + decimalsConverted.format(numOfKilos2Conv) +  " kilograms is "
            + decimalsConverted.format(converted2Pounds) + ".");
        System.out.print("Press Enter to continue ... ");
        System.out.println("");
        keyboard.nextLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Hi all.I'm having trouble getting this together. The output is screwed.  If the user converts to pounds (`readPoundsAndConvert()`) first, the output will say that the converted answer is 0.  If the user convert kilograms first, the kilograms will convert properly and then for somereason the `readPoundsAndConvert()` method will be called an d behave properly.  I have no clue why this is happening and have been spending hours on it.  Can someone tell me how to get this to behave properly?  If you need me to post the rest of the program, I will.

Comment: Too much state. It's killing me. (And making a trivial program into a mess :-/)

Comment: To much state? What do you mean?

Comment: aren't you the guy that just asked the same question and attached the whole code as a .zip? At least consider changing the title to something more related to the actual problem that you're facing here.

Comment: He means you are storing too much data when you could have functions that do the same job. For example, write a function "public double convertKilosToPounds(double kilos)" and use that instead of storing numOfKilos2Conv, converted2Pounds.

Comment: Claudiu -- at least consider that I am completely new to this.  Can you help or not?

Comment: @user: Not meant to be harsh, but I recommend you to read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Balus, that was completely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @pst - Do you mean: `weightconverter.readPoundsAndConvert();weightconverter.displayBothValues();` in WeightConverterTest.java. The seperation of the two methods doesn't make any sense. Why don't you output where you read? No need to save it (add more state). `displayBothValues()` should not exist. You need only one field in WeightConverter: `WEIGHT_CONVERSION_FACTOR`. Others should be local/return values. Not sure if it's helpful but its +- what pst meant, wouldn't worry too much about it. =)

Answer (score 1):

You're using your variables backwards...  In readPoundsAndConvert() you're storing the converted value in converted2Pounds, but when you try to display it, you're reading from converted2Kilograms.

Comment: And you really should learn how to use a debugger.  Go download eclipse learn to debug with it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting `toKilos` and `toPounds` to `true` in your two "convert" methods, but you aren't simultaneously setting the other to `false`. Thus, if you've called one of the convert methods before, when you call `displayBothValues()` both `toKilos` and `toPounds` will be `true` and both will be printed.